# Unable to curl pod IP using containerPort

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Sorry if it's a naive question. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Created POD using this command:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=8888
```

My understand of this command, nginx (application) container will be exposed/available at port 8888

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx   1/1     Running   0          10m   10.244.1.2   node01   <none>           <none>
```

curl -v 10.244.1.2:8888    ===> i am wondering why this failed ?

```
*   Trying 10.244.1.2:8888...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.244.1.2 port 8888 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.244.1.2 port 8888: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.1.2 port 8888: Connection refused
```

curl -v 10.244.1.2     ===> to my surprise this returned 200 success response

```
* Trying 10.244.1.2:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.244.1.2 (10.244.1.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.244.1.2
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If the application is still referring default 80 port, I am wondering about the significance of container port 8888 ?
OK, so it may be used to expose the POD to the outside world.

Let's see that, I went ahead and created service for the POD:

```
kubectl expose pod nginx --port=80 --target-port=8888
```

kubectl get svc

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
nginx        ClusterIP   10.96.214.161   <none>        80/TCP    13m
```

$ curl -v 10.96.214.161       ==> here default port (80) didn't work

```
*   Trying 10.96.214.161:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.96.214.161 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.96.214.161 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.214.161 port 80: Connection refused
```

$ curl -v 10.96.214.161:8888    ==> target port didn't work either

```
*   Trying 10.96.214.161:8888...
* TCP_NODELAY set
....waiting forever
```

Which port do I need to use to make it work? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `nginx` server listen to the port 80. You can see it in their docker image [ref](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nginx/library/nginx/1.18.0-alpine/images/sha256-d7038eae37cfa36cd8e286f6d6daf0df7a445a2da327517b3cde4ba1833adc0c?context=explore).

With `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=8888` what you have done here is you have expose another port along with 80. But the server is still listening on the `80` port.

So, try with target port `80`. For this reason when you tried with other than port `80` it's not working. Try with set `--target-port=8888` to `--target-port=80`.

Or, If you want to change the server port you need to use configmap along with pod to pass custom config to the server.

Comment: ok! that makes sense. thanks for the clarification. Just a followed up question, how can I identify the POD runs on which port by default, if I have no option to check docker file ?

Comment: `kc exec -it -n<name_space>          <pod_name>  -- sh  -c "netstat -tulpn"` with this you can see the  port where server's are listennning.